# Informix SQL Help: Result of a boolean expression is not of boolean type

Tags: sql, informix

I have an SQL statement:

```
UPDATE informix.dv_billing dv 
   SET dv.fee = CASE WHEN ((SELECT dc.mm_discount
                              FROM dv_mm_disc dc
                             WHERE dc.year = YEAR(dv.tdate)
                               AND dc.quarter = quarter(dv.tdate)
                               AND dc.bid=dv.bid
                               AND dc.mm_code=dv.pcode
                              AND dc.ins=dv.ins) = 0)
                     THEN dv.fee ELSE 0
                 END
 WHERE MDY(MONTH('2012-04-05'), 1, YEAR('2012-04-05')) - 2 UNITS MONTH
   AND last_day(DATE('2012-04-05')) 
;
```

The SQL returns the error:

```
Result of a boolean expression is not of boolean type.
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're running into problems with the outer (main) WHERE clause.

You have a condition that is nominally:

```
WHERE expr1 AND expr2
```

which requires both *expr1* and *expr2* to be boolean expressions, but the actual expressions are not booleans — hence the slightly oddly worded error message.

The expression:

```
MDY(MONTH('2012-04-05'), 1, YEAR('2012-04-05')) - 2 UNITS MONTH
```

gives a DATE (or possibly DATETIME YEAR TO DAY) result.  It is reasonable to hypothesize that the `last_day()` function returns the date of the last day in the month containing the given date.

Maybe that last AND should be `=`?

```
 WHERE MDY(MONTH('2012-04-05'), 1, YEAR('2012-04-05')) - 2 UNITS MONTH = last_day(DATE('2012-04-05'))
```

That could be abbreviated to:

```
 WHERE MDY(4, 1, 2012) - 2 UNITS MONTH = last_day(DATE('2012-04-05'))
```

I'm not sure when that condition would ever map to true...but that is a separate discussion.  I do recognize that the '2012-04-05' is likely a query parameter, simplified for the purpose of asking the question, so the abbreviation is not general in valid, but I seems unlikely that the first day of a month will ever be the last day of any month (but a lot hinges on what is in that `last_day()` function).

Comment: You're right.. I forgot to put comparator for where expression. The query become:
UPDATE informix.dv_billing dv 
SET dv.fee = CASE WHEN ((   SELECT dc.mm_discount 
                            FROM dv_mm_disc dc 
                            WHERE dc.year = YEAR(dv.tradedate) AND dc.quarter = quarter(dv.tradedate) AND dc.boardid=dv.boardid AND dc.mm_code=dv.participantcode AND dc.instrument=dv.instrid)=0) THEN dv.fee ELSE 0 END 
WHERE dv.tradedate BETWEEN MDY(MONTH('2012-04-05'), 1, YEAR('2012-04-05')) - 2 UNITS MONTH AND last_day(DATE('2012-04-05'))
GO

Comment: A BETWEEN AND condition makes a lot more sense!